# Add a jar file to Gradle classpath at runtime and not at compile time?

Tags: java, gradle, classpath

Typically when adding a JAR to include with Gradle compilation I do the following:

`compile files('lib/sentiment-models.jar')`

However, since the JAR I'm trying to include is quite big (200MB) my goal is to instead include it at runtime, similar to how you would add files to the classpath using the `java` command:

`java -cp lib/sentiment-models.jar:. -jar /app/server.jar`

So is there a way to use `gradle run` while including files at runtime, preferably in the `build.gradle` config file?

Thanks!

#### Update

I also tried

`runtime files('lib/sentiment-models.jar')`

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are using the Java plugin. Please check the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), section `Dependency management`. Try this one:

> compileOnly Compile time only dependencies, not used at runtime

This should compile your project and the huge jar should not be included in the distribution. How you will refer it in runtime largely depends on your project type.